# Postfix - Forward domain e-mail to personal e-mail with ability to reply as if from domain e-mail

Tags: url-rewriting, postfix-mta

## Question

Is it possible with postfix, and if so how, to forward e-mails from a domain e-mail address (E.G: webmaster@theclientsdomain.com) to a personal e-mail account, while retaining the ability to reply from that g-mail account as webmaster@theclientsdomain.com).

Complex solutions, such as using complex address rewriting rules, are O.K (In-fact, I have posted a related question  which may form a solution to this question if it is answered).

## Context

I'm currently setting up a website for a client, who wants e-mail addresses for their domain, however they do not want mailboxes on the server.

Instead, they want to have the domain addresses forward to their personal addresses.
This is not a problem, and google has shown me how to do this.

The problem comes from the fact they want any replies they send from their personal address to come from the domain address instead, which I have been unable to find out how to do.

## Note

I have never set up postfix, or any mail daemon before, so if answers could be tailored for someone with little experience that would be great.